# Attribute error when attempting to get a value for field

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I'm working with the django rest framework and the serializer I'm trying to use is creating errors. I'm trying to do something like https://gist.github.com/anonymous/7463dce5b0bfcf9b6767 but I still get the error. the models are

```
class Visitor(models.Model):

user = models.OneToOneField(User)
check_ins = models.IntegerField(default=0)

@classmethod
def create(cls, username, email, password):
    user = User.objects.create_user(username, email, password)
    visitor = cls(user=user)
    visitor.save()
    return visitor

def __str__(self):
    return self.user.username
```

and the default user class and the serializers are

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model=User
        fields = ('username')

class VisitorSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    user = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model=Visitor
        fields = ('id','check_ins','user')
```

I get this error

Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `user` on serializer `VisitorSerializer`.
The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet` instance.
Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'user'.

Comment: Have you made sure that your Visitor models's indentation is correct? Your Visitor model looks otherwise alright, but the create and __str__ methods are outside of your class.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The issue is that you are passing a queryset into your serializer without setting the `many` flag. The error is telling you that the serializer is trying to access `queryset.user` when it should be accessing `visitor.user`, so you need to tell the serializer that there are multiple objects (instead of a single one) by passing `many=True`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38800134/manyrelatedmanager-object-has-no-attribute-product . Could you please see this question?If i do many=True, then i wont get form field.