# AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field on serializer

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

Trying to get a `manytomany` relationship in django but I'm getting the following error -

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on serializer GenreSerializer.
>   The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the Movie instance.
>   Original exception text was: 'Movie' object has no attribute 'name'.

There is a similar answer here recommending setting `many=True`, but it doesn't work - 
[Attribute error when attempting to get a value for field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562054/attribute-error-when-attempting-to-get-a-value-for-field)

models.py

```
class Genre(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255,unique=True)

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.name

class Movie(models.Model):
  mname = models.CharField(max_length=255)
  genres = models.ManyToManyField(Genre,related_name='movies')

  def __unicode__(self):
    return self.mname
```

serializers.py

```
class GenreSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  class Meta:
    model = Genre
    fields = ('name','id')

class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
  genres = GenreSerializer(many=True, read_only=True)    

  class Meta:
    model = Movie
    fields = ('id','genres','mname')
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^genres/$', views.GenreList.as_view()),
url(r'^genres/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)$', views.GenreDetail.as_view()),
]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns)
```

views.py

```
class GenreList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
  queryset = Genre.objects.all()
  serializer_class = GenreSerializer


class GenreDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
  serializer_class = GenreSerializer

  def get_queryset(self):
    genres = Genre.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk', None))
    movies = Movie.objects.filter(genres=genres)
    return movies
```

Comment: did you include the models in serializer.py?  ie. `from app.models import Movie, Genre`

Comment: Yes, I've done the imports.

Comment: can you update your question with how you are calling them?  Or is it compiling with this error?  Thanks.

Comment: @arcee123 done. It complies with these errors. It's only when I try to access `/genres/pk` that I get the error

Comment: Try what CptLemming says...if not try ditching your "related_name" attribute.  Could be killing your reverse-relationship.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Similar to your other question, you are using the incorrect serializer on your `GenreDetail` view. You need to add the serializer for the type of models you are returning from `get_queryset`:

```
class GenreDetail(generics.RetrieveUpdateDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = MovieSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        genres = Genre.objects.get(pk=self.kwargs.get('pk', None))
        movies = Movie.objects.filter(genres=genres)
        return movies
```

Answer (score 15):

If yout are using a function based serializer, and wanted to fetch all the information of the ModelSerializer. Then use `many=True`

```py
@api_view()
def movie_list(request):

    movies = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer = MovieSerializer(movies)
    print(serializer)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

For the above code, the response was

> Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field `name` on
> serializer `MovieSerializer`. The serializer field might be named
> incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the `QuerySet`
> instance. Original exception text was: 'QuerySet' object has no
> attribute 'name'.

If we just add `many=True` in serializer = MovieSerializer(movies, many=True)`:

```py
@api_view()
def movie_list(request):

    movies = Movie.objects.all()
    serializer = MovieSerializer(movies, many=True)
    print(serializer)
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

Then the output we get is
[image: please replace this obnoxious image with text]

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code, error messages, or other textual data.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors)

Comment: so simple and useful :) thanks...

Answer (score 1):

Let just take a simple example model in which you have three fields

```py
from django.db import models

class Movie(models):
  name = models.CharField()
  description = models.TextField()
  created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

If you're using this in serializer field then you have to pass argument "many=true" along with model name for example

```py
movie = Movie.objects.all()
serializer = MovieSerializer(movie, many=True)
```

this is caused because when you have more than one objects(fields) in your model and you want to loop through every field for that we use "many=True"

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).